# In Android, how to pass surface to MediaCodec::configure API

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a simple video player using `MediaExtractor` and `MediaCodec` API.

I am able to extract the individual tracks of a TS (Transport Stream) file.
I am also able to create the decoder and configure it and able to decode the content.

When I want to render the video on a `surface`, I understand that we should give the surface as a parameter to `MediaCodec.configure`.

```
status_t MediaCodec::configure (MediaFormat format, Surface surface, MediaCrypto crypto, int flags)
```

Now, I couldn't find any example on how to create a `surface` and pass that to the `configure` function.
Can somebody please help me out ?

Comment: How were you able to extract the individual tracks?? Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

First implement TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener as:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

private TextureView m_surface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    m_surface = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.textureView);
    m_surface.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
}
```

Now pass the Surface to MediaCodec like this

```
m_codec.configure(format,new Surface(m_surface.getSurfaceTexture()), null, 0);
```